# InDesign: are columns inside of a text frame individually customizable?

Tags: adobe-indesign, formatting

When I create a text frame with columns, is it possible to adjust every single columns and gaps width individual? Like in the picture, there is one text frame with 3 columns (different widths) and also the gaps are different.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. You need to use separate text frames instead of columns. To quote from [Adobe](https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/creating-text-text-frames.html) directly:

> *You cannot create columns of unequal width in a text frame. To create
>   columns of unequal width or height, add threaded text frames
>   side-by-side on either a document page or a master page.*

Comment: Yup. I was going to point out the possibility for fluid columns. But after the question edit, it's a hard "no" :)